# python rock paper scissors counter

Tags: python

I'm building a rock paper scissors game and I would like to add a counter to the code I already have.

I want to count wins, losses and ties, and print these when the player does not want to play anymore.

This code does just about everything else I set out to do. I have seen a few other ideas on the site, but none of them seem to be adaptable to my code. Any ideas?
Here is the code:

```
import random

def rock(rand):

    if rand == (1):
        print("Tie Game!")
    elif rand == (2):
        print("Your rock got covered by opponent's paper. You Lose!")
    elif rand == (3):
        print("You crushed the opponent's scissors with your rock! You Win!")
        print("Good game!")

def paper(rand):

    if rand == (1):
        print("You covered opponent's rock with your paper. You Win!")
        print("Good game!")
    elif rand == (2):
        print("Tie Game!")
    elif rand == (3):
        print("Your opponent cut your paper with its scissors. You Lose!")

def scissors(rand):

    if rand == (1):
        print("Your opponent's rock crushed your scissors. You Lose!")
    elif rand == (2):
        print("Your scissors cut opponent's paper. You Win!")
        print("Good game!")
    elif rand == (3):
        print("Tie Game!")

def main():

    name = input("What is your name? ")

    print("Hello, " + name + "! I'm a rock paper scissors game.")

    while True:
        choice = input("Would you like to play? (yes/no) ").upper()[0]
        if choice == "N":
            print("Let's play later!")
            break
        elif choice == "Y":
            print("Ok, lets play!")
            print("Rules: Rock breaks Scissors, Scissors cuts Paper, Paper covers Rock. ")
            raw = input("Choose rock, paper, or scissors ").upper()
            try:
                answer = raw[0]
            except:
                IndexError
                print("Illegal input! Exiting.")
                break


            rand = random.randint(1, 3)  # 1 = rock, 2 =Paper 3 = Scissors
            if answer == "S":
                scissors(rand)
            elif answer == "P":
                paper(rand)
            elif answer == "R":
                rock(rand)
            else:
                print("Enter a valid answer!")
main()
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I want to count wins, losses and ties, and print these when the player does not want to play anymore.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What ideas seemed promising but weren't appropriate, and why?

Comment: As a hint: do you know about either (a) returning multiple values from a function, or (b) global variables? Either of those should make this pretty easy. Even without those, you just have to return a single value that means either win/loss/tie and write another if/elif/elif statement in `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to put all the methods in a class instead of using global variables.
Here you go.

```
import random

my_win = 0
my_loss = 0
my_tie = 0



def rock(rand):

    global my_tie, my_loss, my_win
    if rand == (1):
        print("Tie Game!")
        my_tie += 1
    elif rand == (2):
        print("Your rock got covered by opponent's paper. You Lose!")
        my_loss += 1
    elif rand == (3):
        print("You crushed the opponent's scissors with your rock! You Win!")
        print("Good game!")
        my_win += 1

def paper(rand):

    if rand == (1):
        print("You covered opponent's rock with your paper. You Win!")
        print("Good game!")
        my_win += 1
    elif rand == (2):
        print("Tie Game!")
        my_tie += 1
    elif rand == (3):
        print("Your opponent cut your paper with its scissors. You Lose!")
        my_loss += 1

def scissors(rand):

    if rand == (1):
        print("Your opponent's rock crushed your scissors. You Lose!")
        my_loss += 1
    elif rand == (2):
        print("Your scissors cut opponent's paper. You Win!")
        print("Good game!")
        my_win += 1
    elif rand == (3):
        print("Tie Game!")
        my_tie += 1

def main():

    name = input("What is your name? ")

    print("Hello, " + name + "! I'm a rock paper scissors game.")

    while True:
        choice = input("Would you like to play? (yes/no) ").upper()[0]
        if choice == "N":
            print("Let's play later!")
            break
        elif choice == "Y":
            print("Ok, lets play!")
            print("Rules: Rock breaks Scissors, Scissors cuts Paper, Paper covers Rock. ")
            raw = input("Choose rock, paper, or scissors ").upper()
            try:
                answer = raw[0]
            except:
                print("Illegal input! Exiting.")
                break


            rand = random.randint(1, 3)  # 1 = rock, 2 =Paper 3 = Scissors
            if answer == "S":
                scissors(rand)
            elif answer == "P":
                paper(rand)
            elif answer == "R":
                rock(rand)
            else:
                print("Enter a valid answer!")
    print ("You win %d times!" % my_win)
    print ("You lose %d times!" % my_loss)
    print ("You tie %d times!" % my_tie)
main()
```

OUTPUT:

```
What is your name? a
Hello, a! I'm a rock paper scissors game.
Would you like to play? (yes/no) y
Ok, lets play!
Rules: Rock breaks Scissors, Scissors cuts Paper, Paper covers Rock. 
Choose rock, paper, or scissors Rock
Tie Game!
Would you like to play? (yes/no) no
Let's play later!
You win 0 times!
You lose 0 times!
You tie 1 times!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: That did it. I had tired some similar solutions, but I was not using the global wins, losses, and ties in the correct places. Thanks for you help!